# Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.IllegalAccessError AND Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android

I am configuring google sign in API on my app and i am getting illegalAccessError when i launch the app and Looper.prepare() error log when i click on the google sign in button

```
09-03 02:34:12.615 13855-14016/com.xyz I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-03 02:34:13.027 13855-13944/com.xyz D/FA: Connected to remote service
09-03 02:34:13.027 13855-13944/com.xyz V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
09-03 02:34:13.034 13855-13944/com.xyz E/FA: Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/app/com.xyz-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes17.dex): com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzEd(Unknown Source)
09-03 02:34:18.028 13855-13944/com.xyz V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
09-03 02:34:33.162 13855-13944/com.xyz V/FA: Activity paused, time: 362334438
09-03 02:34:33.165 13855-15188/com.xyz E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-03 02:34:33.165 13855-15188/com.xyz D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
09-03 02:34:33.196 13855-13855/com.xyz V/FA: onActivityCreated
09-03 02:34:33.220 13855-13944/com.xyz V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 362334496
09-03 02:34:33.221 13855-15190/com.xyz E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-03 02:34:33.221 13855-15190/com.xyz D/AppTracker: App Event: start
09-03 02:34:33.296 13855-13944/com.xyz V/FA: Activity paused, time: 362334572
09-03 02:34:33.297 13855-15191/com.xyz E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-03 02:34:33.298 13855-15191/com.xyz D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
09-03 02:34:34.298 13855-13944/com.xyz D/FA: Application backgrounded. Logging engagement
09-03 02:34:34.304 13855-13944/com.xyz I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
09-03 02:34:34.317 13855-13944/com.xyz D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=20742}]
09-03 02:34:34.319 13855-13944/com.xyz V/FA: Using measurement service
09-03 02:34:34.319 13855-13944/com.xyz V/FA: Connecting to remote service
09-03 02:34:34.328 13855-13944/com.xyz D/FA: Connected to remote service
09-03 02:34:34.328 13855-13944/com.xyz V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
09-03 02:34:34.332 13855-13944/com.xyz E/FA: Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/app/com.xyz-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes17.dex): com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzEd(Unknown Source)
09-03 02:34:39.339 13855-13855/com.xyz D/LoginActivity: handleSignInResult:false
09-03 02:34:39.340 13855-13944/com.xyz V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 362340616
09-03 02:34:39.341 13855-15331/com.xyz E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-03 02:34:39.341 13855-15331/com.xyz D/AppTracker: App Event: start
09-03 02:34:39.367 13855-13944/com.xyz V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
09-03 02:34:49.054 13855-13944/com.xyz V/FA: Activity paused, time: 362349528
09-03 02:34:49.057 13855-15634/com.xyz E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-03 02:34:49.057 13855-15634/com.xyz D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
09-03 02:34:49.093 13855-13855/com.xyz D/FirebaseApp: Notifying background state change listeners.
09-03 02:34:50.089 13855-13944/com.xyz D/FA: Application backgrounded. Logging engagement
09-03 02:34:50.092 13855-13944/com.xyz D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=8912}]
09-03 02:34:50.092 13855-13944/com.xyz V/FA: Using measurement service
09-03 02:34:50.092 13855-13944/com.xyz V/FA: Connecting to remote service
09-03 02:34:50.111 13855-13944/com.xyz D/FA: Connected to remote service
09-03 02:34:50.111 13855-13944/com.xyz V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
09-03 02:34:50.116 13855-13944/com.xyz E/FA: Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/app/com.xyz-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes17.dex): com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzEd(Unknown Source)
09-03 02:34:55.153 13855-13944/com.xyz V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
```

This is my build.grade(project level)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Build.grade(App level)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is my Login Activity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;


    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private TextView mStatusTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);
        loadFontsOnStartUp();

        GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail().build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions).build();

        findViewById(R.id.google_login).setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

        mStatusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testViewForLoginGoogle);
    }

    /**
     * Adding custom font "berkshireswash" to the app title
     * Adding custom font "Lato-Light" to all text on login screen
     */
    public void loadFontsOnStartUp() {

        Typeface customFontNunitoRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Nunito-Regular.ttf");
        Typeface customFontBerkshire = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/berkshireswash-regular.ttf");

        TextView appName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_name);
        appName.setTypeface(customFontBerkshire);

        Button fbLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.facebook_login);
        fbLogin.setTypeface(customFontNunitoRegular);

        Button googleLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.google_login);
        googleLogin.setTypeface(customFontNunitoRegular);

        Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setTypeface(customFontNunitoRegular);

        TextView forgotPasswordTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forgot_password);
        forgotPasswordTextView.setTypeface(customFontNunitoRegular);

        TextView signUpTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sign_up);
        signUpTextView.setTypeface(customFontNunitoRegular);

        TextView termsConditionsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.terms_and_conditons);
        termsConditionsTextView.setTypeface(customFontNunitoRegular);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.google_login:
                signIn();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.tempSignInGoogleTestString, acct.getEmail()));
            updateUI(true);
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

    private void updateUI(boolean signedIn) {
        if (signedIn) {
            findViewById(R.id.login_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not really sure whats happening here. It was working fine before and then i changed the Android sdk version to 25 because i was adding the facebook sdk and it was not supported by version 26. It stopped working then, so i rolled back everything to when it was working but its not wroking now. Any ideas whats happening here?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0` with a Support Library above 25.0.0 as the per [the release notes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#rev25-0-0):

> [ContextCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html) constructor has been made protected. This class should not be publicly instantiated, but it may be extended by support libraries targeting newer API levels.

And `9.0.0` was not built with that limitation in mind, causing the error you are experiencing. You must update your `play-services-auth` dependency to a more recent version. The latest, and only one compatible with targeting API 26, is [11.2.0](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#august_2017_-_version_1120).

Comment: i did that but it says : failed to resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.0

Comment: Did you read the note on using the `maven.google.com` repository on the 11.2.0 release notes I linked?